# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'route.params.myText')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```
function Screen2({route, navigation}) {
  
    
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>{route.params.myText}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

export default Screen2;
```

Here myText is a string that is passed from other screen(login Screen).

login Screen---------------------------------------

```
<View>
                <Button style={styles.loginBTN} title="Login"
                onPress={() => {navigation.navigate('Screen2'), {myText: "hello react-native"}}} />
            </View>
```

Comment: please explain better, what is the issue, what u have tried, a code snippets would be helpful to all others

Answer (score 0):

I guess there's a situation (maybe before unmounting) that `route` or `route.params` is undefined,

you can solve it this way

```
function Screen2({route, navigation}) {  
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>

        //I added question mark before the dots (optional chaining)
        <Text>{route?.params?.myText}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
export default Screen2;
```

it's called [optional chaining](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwikpO_2-Mf1AhXHgv0HHSanC9kQFnoECAYQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FOperators%2FOptional_chaining&usg=AOvVaw3fLcEvZqB0O4DQx47AqDMT), according to Mozilla

> It enables you to read the value of a property located deep within a chain of connected objects without having to check that each reference in the chain is valid.

Comment: error has gone but I am unable to display the data that I want on the screen2. please help me...

Comment: @moinmaniar have you checked the console for errors? please provide more information, or it would be very helpful if you could share the source code (for example in Github or Codepen , or through a link here, etc) so I could debug it

Answer (score 0):

your login button press should pass the params like below

```
onPress={() = navigation.navigate("Screen2", {
          myText: "hello react-native",
        })
}
```